# prevent closing Foundation modal when clicking outside of the modal

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

I don't want the modal to go away when I click on the background. I'd like it to keep display until I click the button inside the modal. Here is a codepen link

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdNXGd

here is the angular code

```
app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);
app.directive('modal', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      show: '='
    },
    replace: true, // Replace with the template below
    transclude: true, // we want to insert custom content inside the directive
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.hideModal = function() {
        scope.show = false;
      };
    },
    template: "<div class='ng-modal' ng-show='show'>"+
                "<div class='reveal-modal' data-options='close_on_background_click:false' ng-show='show'>"+
                  "<div ng-transclude></div>"+
                  "<a class='close-reveal-modal' ng-click='hideModal()'>&#215;</a>"+
                "</div>"+
                "<div class='reveal-modal-bg' ng-click='hideModal()'></div>"+
              "</div>"
  };
});

app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.modalShown = false;
  $scope.toggleModal = function() {
    $scope.modalShown = !$scope.modalShown;
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the solution that works. I added

```
backdrop : 'static'
```

into $modal.open

Answer (score 0):

as far as I can tell the answer you've put doesn't work for newer versions of Foundation - the only reference I could find when searching around for `backdrop: 'static'` was for bootstrap modals. The foundation docs are also pretty unhelpful, having only a passing mention of an options parameter (https://get.foundation/sites/docs/reveal.html#advanced-options) without specifying what the possible options are.

However I dug around in the source code and found these options, here they are in case anybody else is trying to do this: (I'm using foundation-sites 6.4x, with some jQuery)

```js
let $modal = $('.my-modal');

let revealModal = new Foundation.Reveal(
  $modal, {
  closeOnClick: false,
  closeOnEsc:   false
});

revealModal.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation from foundation shows that you could also use:

data-close-on-click="false"

This worked for me, i added to the reveal class div, example:

```
<div class="reveal" id="testReveal" data-reveal data-close-on-click="true">
```